# Can anyone say how to include only CDN of Bootstrap in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to validate form using angularjs and angular-material built-in directives including messages under field like, input, select, radio buttons.
There are some specific requirements:

The Form fields should have equal heights
The radio buttons i.e. md-radio should be inline
The location of messages under fields should be similar
The angular-material select i.e. md-select should be width = 100%

Comment: Here is cdn repository of many projects https://cdnjs.com/
and here is bootstrap https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap
Instructions are included on site.

Comment: I'm confused.  Your title doesn't have anything to do with the question body.  What does including CDN of Bootstrap have to do with form validation?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following lines in your index.html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This will load both style file and script file of bootstrap